# Panel: run application in terminal, set terminal application

Tags: launcher, 19.04, mate, .desktop

With a MATE Panel item set to 'application in terminal'

[image: add launcher]

I see `xterm`:

[image: htop in xterm]

I want to change that to `gnome-terminal` (or `mate-terminal` in MATE)

Comment: For the record, glib supports `mate-terminal` since version 2.61.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be hardcoded somewhere to use GNOME Terminal.
The logic behind this seems to be the following: if GNOME Terminal is not found, then desktop-shortcut uses `xterm` as fallback.

We can simulate GNOME Terminal installation on MATE by using a hack - create symlink to MATE Terminal executable:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/mate-terminal /usr/local/bin/gnome-terminal
```

and then run application with MATE Terminal attached.

---

Note: I have faced the same problem with one of my laptops, so I asked [a question](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/is-it-possible-to-define-which-terminal-will-be-used-for-desktop-file-with-terminal-true-application-in-terminal-set/20144?u=norbert_x) on Ubuntu MATE Community. It is great that upcoming Ubuntu MATE 19.10 is not affected by this problem.

Comment: Ah good one! For my issue I needed `ln -sf /usr/bin/mate-terminal /usr/bin/xterm` And yes, I see other good changes coming in 19.10.

Comment: It is OK if you do not have `xterm` package installed. Otherwise it is not recommended as `/usr/bin/xterm` will be overwritten on next upgrade of `xterm` package. You can try to remove `xterm` package with `sudo apt-get remove xterm` and then make symlink in `/usr/local/bin` (this folder is not maintained by APT).

Comment: "It seems to be hardcoded somewhere to use GNOME Terminal": for the record, it's inside glib, see https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glib/-/blob/main/gio/gdesktopappinfo.c (`prepend_terminal_to_vector`)

Answer (score 2):

Or, you can change the drop-down from "Application in Terminal" to just "Application" - and before `htop` provide the full path to the wanted `XXXX-terminal` as this:
  "Name: `/usr/bin/gnome-terminal -e htop`" (consult with man-page or help of the needed terminal application about the correct option format).

Even, maybe, with no change in the "Type" field ...

Comment: OK. My bad. I am using XFCE DE on Ubuntu 14.04. There's a default "Terminal" in "/usr/bin/xfce4-terminal" with this options :
-x, --execute => Execute the remainder of the command line inside the terminal ; 
-e, --command=*htop* => Execute *htop* inside the Terminal ; 
-T, --title="Htop in GNME/MATE Terminal" => For setting the initial window title for the Terminal .